# How to find the exact elemental value in the loop?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code to implement a basic optimization method to maintain minimum error between an observed and simulated profile. I am doing this with simple root mean square error. The whole code I have given here for convinence.

```
    %% Vegetation profile along a hillslope
    % Parameters
    Tv = 1;             % values are {1,2,3,5,10}
    %Kvg = 0.3;          % according to the Tv values Kvg=1/Tv
    Kvg = 1/Tv;
    Kvd = 0.5;          % valuse are {0.1,0.5,1,5,10}
    Tcv = 10;           % values are {20,50,80,130,180}
    q = (1/3);
    Nv = (1:1:10);               %(Kvd*Tcv)/Kvg; range is given for the parameter
    m = 2/3;
    n = 2/3;

    %% Horizontal coordinate and length scale
    x = 0:1:100;
    L = 100;
    x_non = x/L;
    Ne =10;               %L/Tcv;


    %% Vegetation profile on the slope
    v = zeros(length(x_non),length(Nv));
    for i = 1:length(x_non)
    for j = 1:length(Nv)
    v(i,j) = (1/(1+Nv(j)*(Ne^q)*(x_non(i)^q)));
    end
    end

   %% importing the excel file containg real dataset
   obs_data = xlsread('model_data.xlsx'); % 1-distance, 2-elevation, 3-  vegetation, 4-slope


   %% root mean square error between real and synthetic dataset of vegetation

  rmse_v = zeros(length(x_non),length(Nv));
  err_v = zeros(1,length(Nv));
  for j=1:length(Nv)
  rmse_v(:,j)=(obs_data(:,3)-v(:,j)).^2;
  err_v(1,j)= sqrt(mean(rmse_v(:,j)));

  end
```

Now I have to extract the value of Nv for which the rmse_v is minimum. The Nv value for which the aforesaid statement is true has to be used in the next session.

```
    Nt = (1:1:100);
    % Slope profile on the x direction
    s = zeros(length(x_non),length(Nt));
    for i = 1:length(x_non)
    for j = 1:length(Nt)
    s(i,j)=((Ne^q)/Nt(j))*(x_non(i)^(q-m))+(1/(Nt(j)*(x_non(i)^m)*(1+Nv*(Ne^q)...
    *(x_non(i)^q))))^(1/n);
   end
   end
```

I shall be grateful to get the way of writing the way to do the particular thing.

Thank you.
Regards

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. What is `Nt`? If by all this you mean, you want to extract the value in `Nv` at the index `i`, where `rmse_v(i) = min(rmse_v)` -> then look at `min` command, the second output argument will give you the index. Then just extract the value from `Nv` at that index. Also, learn to explain your problem in a more abstract manner. You don't really need to show entire code. Just take variables `x, y, z` etc. and frame your problem concisely, so that maximum people will understand.

Comment: I am a very novice person in matlab programming. What you said was correct as per my problem. I will try that out. I will also learn to write the quest correctly.